# Loopj's onFailure is called with null response

Tags: java, android, http, loopj

I am using loopj for android to talk to my server. One of my requests takes a long time so I am using setTimeout(30) for the AsyncClient. However, loopj is always firing onFailure with null response. The weird thing is that the server keeps running the script (I checked it).

**So I have the problem of the server running correctly, but loopj decides that the request fails prematurely. I suspect it is a timeout issue, but setTimeout is not doing the job, any suggestions please?**

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might struggle with this: The problem was that setTimeOut's argument is in milliseconds not seconds, I was setting it to 30 milliseconds.

Reminder to focus when reading docs.